# What arguments in metric are and set in metric space is?

Tags: metric-spaces

I am trying to understand what metric space is (I need it to understand what Minkowski space is, as one of the key to understand why Twins paradox is not a paradox (if it is not indeed)).

I understood that metric space is described by a *set* and a *metric*.

**First confusion**

A set, as I understand is just a bunch of numbers, that space consists of. Here I already have doubts. Is it some specifically described bunch of numbers (by a function, for example, or manually), or it meant a group of numbers from the hierarchy, like Natural, Rational, Complex, etc.?

**Second confusion**

A metric, as I understand, is just a function, that defines how to calculate the distance between … and here I also have confusion.

Distance between points (which can be vectors entities, i.e. be described by two or more numbers) made up from numbers from the *Set*, **or** “distance” between directly two (or more?) numbers from the *Set*.

The second one actually means some fundamental stuff, i.e. it should describe, what is the distance between numbers, like between 5 and 3, so it rule can be, that it wouldn’t be 2.

I always see in literature, that **metric** is written as

$$d(x,y)$$
$$d(x,x)=0$$

What does x, and y mean there?

**Third confusion**

Probably, more general, a *metric* $d$ of some *set* $M$ is described as

$$d: M \times M -> R$$

What does it mean? Does $\times$ mean cross product? Why $M$ is twice?

Comment: Keep in mind that Minkowski space is not a metric space.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, well, yes, maybe I a bit confused, but, as written on Wikipedia, it’s kinda metric space. At least, I think, it will be useful to clearly understand what metric space is, to understand what pseudo-Euclidian space is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set is just a collection of objects.  The objects are not necessarily numbers; variables, geometric shapes, or even other sets would do just as fine.  For instance, $A:=\{\text {apple, \{banana, orange\}}\}$ is a set.

A metric space is an ordered pair $(M,d)$ where $M$ is a set and $d$ is a *metric* on $M$.  A metric on $M$ is a function from $M\times M$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies certain properties [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition_and_illustration).  Also, $\times$ is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

In plain words, a metric takes in two elements from the set $M$ and maps them to a real number that represents a notion of "distance" between those two elements. So the notation $d(x,y)$ represents a distance between two objects $x,y$ that live in $M$. The linked wiki page also has common examples of metrics.

Comment: Thanks, actually I read that article before asking. Now I understand, what that cross means.

Comment: Although, still, have a bit confusion: if there is a set $M$ with entities of different type, for example: M = [46(number), [1,2,3](vector)], how do I write metric function, in particular it’s arguments?

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd You just assign a distance for every pair of elements from the set $M$ in a way that obeys the properties of a metric, whether or not the elements are the same "type" of object, e.g. $d(46, (1,2,3))=1$.  If $M$ is finite, that would mean specifying $M\choose 2$ distances.  "Type" of object doesn't matter; for instance, we may measure the distance between a point and a plane.

Comment: Okay, but how do You write it as a formula? In Your example, You have already passed, arguments (46 and (1,2,3)), and did not specify the equation of the function, just wrote the result. 
In case of arguments, probably it can be just x and y, undependably on type.
But how in function's equation You will know, what type is variable, if it can various?

Comment: For example in some programming languages, in C++, in particular, type of variables should be specified in function (as well as return value of function): `int func(int a, Array b)`. In other languages, in function's body programmer can determine variable type using conditional statements: `if(typeof a == 'integer')dosomething;`

Comment: I probably rewrite my question a bit. Although, no, I will ask another question

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd  A function does not need to be written as a compact formula.  Please check out the definition of a function. A function is just a map that specifies a value in the codomain for every element in its domain.  Nothing more.  For your example, $M$ just had two elements so $M\times M$ has four elements.  So a function on $M\times M$ needs to assign values to four elements.  However, it is enough to specify the value of $d(46,(1,2,3))$ because properties of a metric pin down the other values (check the wiki page for properties).

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd In summary, I would suggest thinking about each element in a set as a generic object. "Type" may be important in a programming context, but not in this particular context.