# In function, how to handle variable, that can be different entities?

Tags: functions

I was asking a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640634/what-arguments-in-metric-are-and-set-in-metric-space-is) about metric space, and metric function, and was confused of what values can a set contain, respectively to the fact, that this set elements are passed as arguments to the metric function:

$$d: M \times M\space to\space \mathbb{R}$$

@Golden_Ratio answered that set may contain from entities of different types, for example

$$M:=\{\text {1(number), \{2, 3\}(vector, array)}\}$$

And arguments of the metric function are provided no matter of the expected type, just like

$$d(x, y)$$

If it is true, how to write the function equation that handles different types of variales, i.e. $x$ may be number as well as vector or a plane, or something else?

If there are kinda conditional statements in math, like in programming, so we can write

```
d(x, y) =  2x + y.x*y.y, typeof x == integer OR 2y + x.x*x.y
```

Comment: First, re-read the (accepted by you) answer to your previous post. The simple example is the distance $d$ between points in the cartesian plane: the cartesian plane is $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, i.e. each element (point) is identified by a *pair* of numbers. The distance maps every pair to a (real) number. Thus $d : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that means that the function is $d(P,Q)=r$.

Comment: If instead of the cartesian plane $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ you have a generic metric space $M$, the function $d$ maps every pair of "points" of $M$ into a real number. Thus, we have $d : M \times M \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, so statement, that a set can consists of different type elements is wrong?

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd  a set can consist of whatever you want, as long as it is well-defined.

Comment: @Randall, so how then in function's body to know which variable (that is an element from multi-type $M$) has which type?

Comment: A function has a domain a set $D$, and $D$ has well-defined elements, so I know what I can plug into it.  This has nothing to do with any kind of "type" at all.

Comment: @Randall, *so I know what I can plug into it* - how? Can You please provide an example of function where domain consists of entities of different types?

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd again, "types" are not the way to think about this.  math $\neq$ computer science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with understanding functions and their inputs as long as you know well the *definition* of a function in terms of sets.  This has nothing to do with declaring certain objects having certain "types."  A function $f: D \to Z$ has domain a well-defined set $D$, so the elements of $D$ are what you plug in, whatever those elements might be (that is up to the user).

One natural example of a function that one could say has inputs of different "types" (but again, that's only confusing a situation that is already clear) is scalar multiplication of vectors.  To scale a two-component vector $\mathbf{v} = \langle a, b \rangle \in \mathbb{R}^2$ by a scalar $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we write $c\mathbf{v}= \langle ca, cb\rangle$.  This **defines** a function
$$
s: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2
$$
via
$$
s(c,\mathbf{v})=c\mathbf{v}.
$$
Thus $s$ is a function with **clearly defined domain** $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2$ and there are no doubts about the ingredients of the function or how it operates.  If you wish to think about the domain as one having two "types"--one scalar, one vector--that's not harmful.

Comment: Do You know what bijection is?

Comment: Yes.  How does that matter?

Comment: Bijection is injection and surjection, but, function can be also only injectional or surjectional

Comment: I don't follow. That makes no sense with the current question.

Comment: In case of surjectional function A to B, all B elements must have at least one corresponding value from A. So I can pass 2 numbers as arguments to function that expects to receive one as a vector, and it should fail

Comment: Your first sentence is a true statement, but what in the world does that have to do with your question?

Comment: If you pass two numbers into a function that expects a vector input, you did NOT put two inputs into the function.  You only put in one, a vector.

Comment: answering Your last comment. You understood wrong - if I have function $f$ with to arguments $x$ and $y$, and function expects to have at least one of them to be vector and I pass both as number, should not it fail?

Comment: Of course it should fail.  Again, no one here said that it shouldn't fail.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because it is no longer clear to me that you have asked what you've intended to ask.

Comment: Okay, from another side. In function's equation, in case of vectors as arguments, can I operate with separate vector values? For example, the function is $f(x)$ where $x$ should be vector, and I want this function to return a **number**, that equals first vector element value multiplied by some another value, i.e. $f(x) = x.x * 10$. Can it be possible in math?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  I can define a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(\langle a, b \rangle) = 10a$.

Comment: Got You! So now You clearly specify "type" of the argument, using that brackets. That mean that You expecting to receive a vector

Comment: The "type" was already specifed when I said the domain was $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: What if I also want to use numbers in domain?

Comment: Then do it (see the example in my answer).  Your only job is to **well-define** the domain for the reader so that the inputs are exactly clear.

Comment: $f(<a,b>,c) = 10a * c$ ?

Comment: So, from this discussion it means, that mathematical formalism supposes just a letter as an argument to be a number. Variable, specified as a letter means a number. If I want to specify vector (which values are numbers) and operate with its members separately, I need to specify them as separate variables. 

Thanks